# fftw_mpi_plan_dft_3d fails with Segmentation fault

Tags: fortran, mpi, fftw

The following 3D complex FFT Fortran MPI program runs when the number of processes P = 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16. But, it fails when P = 12 with the following error at the place where function fftw_mpi_plan_dft_3d is called.

"Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference."

Why does this program fail with P = 12?

```
PROGRAM test
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING

  IMPLICIT NONE
  INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
  INCLUDE 'fftw3-mpi.f03'

  INTEGER :: ier
  integer(C_INTPTR_T), parameter :: L = 256
  integer(C_INTPTR_T), parameter :: N = 256
  integer(C_INTPTR_T), parameter :: M = 48
  type(C_PTR) :: plan, cdata
  complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), pointer :: data(:,:,:)
  integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: i, j, alloc_local, local_M, local_j_offset

  CALL MPI_INIT(ier)

  CALL fftw_mpi_init

  alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_3d(M, N, L, MPI_COMM_WORLD, local_M, local_j_offset)
  cdata = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local)
  CALL C_F_POINTER(cdata, data, [L, N, local_M])

  plan = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_3d(M, N, L, data, data, MPI_COMM_WORLD, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE)

  CALL fftw_destroy_plan(plan)
  CALL fftw_free(cdata)

  CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ier)
  STOP

END PROGRAM test
```

Comment: Maybe the FFTW developers could help you. They're reachable at the address at the bottom of this webpage http://www.fftw.org/#documentation

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: In which step does it crash? Is the answer correct when it works?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error. Which compiler and compiler options do you use? Which FFTW version? Which MPI library? Which version?

Comment: Could you try to use different buffer for the input and the output ? For non-mpi fftw, the flag `FFTW_IN_PLACE` must be specified in such cases. See http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_3.html . I assume that in place transform is not functionning correctly with fftw-mpi...

Comment: It crashes at "plan = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_3d(M, N, L, ...). When it works, it finishes with no errors. (As you see, only plan is created and no FFT is done in the program.)

Comment: Here are versions of the softwares: OS X 10.11.3, compiler: gcc 5 + mpich 3.2, compiler option, -O0 -I$(HOME)/local/include -L$(HOME)/local/lib -lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3, FFTW: 3.3.4

Comment: Using different buffer for the input and the output didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Vladimir F, could you let me know your environment where you could not reproduce the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem with fftw_mpi_plan_dft_c2r on a Cray XE6 using cray-mpich 7.1.3.  It doesn't matter if fftw is compiled with gcc, Cray cc, or Intel icc.  The segmentation fault only occurs for certain combinations of array dimensions and number of processors.  One combination that results in a segfault is array size 1920,3840,3840 on 128 processes.  As with the original post, I used FFTW_ESTIMATE and so no transform is done by the planner.  Stack trace follows.

```
#0  0x00000000008f26f0 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000004179bb in fftw_plan_destroy_internal (ego=0x8e2af0) at plan.c:49
#2  0x000000000040d755 in mkplan (ego_=0x8def60, p_=0x8f1440, plnr=0x8d6110)
at transpose-pairwise.c:467
#3  0x0000000000418a07 in invoke_solver (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8f1440, s=0x8def60,
nflags=0x7fffffff4fc0) at planner.c:486
#4  0x0000000000418b9c in search0 (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8f1440, slvndx=0x7fffffff4fcc,
flagsp=0x7fffffff4fc0) at planner.c:529
#5  0x0000000000418db8 in search (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8f1440, slvndx=0x7fffffff4fcc,
flagsp=0x7fffffff4fc0) at planner.c:600
#6  0x00000000004191d8 in mkplan (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8f1440) at planner.c:711
#7  0x0000000000419d35 in fftw_mkplan_d (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8f1440) at planner.c:970
#8  0x0000000000411d47 in mkplan (ego_=0x8df140, p_=0x8df930, plnr=0x8d6110)
at dft-rank1-bigvec.c:165
#9  0x0000000000418a07 in invoke_solver (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8df930, s=0x8df140,
nflags=0x7fffffff5290) at planner.c:486
#10 0x0000000000418b9c in search0 (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8df930, slvndx=0x7fffffff529c,
flagsp=0x7fffffff5290) at planner.c:529
#11 0x0000000000418db8 in search (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8df930, slvndx=0x7fffffff529c,
flagsp=0x7fffffff5290) at planner.c:600
#12 0x00000000004191d8 in mkplan (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8df930) at planner.c:711
#13 0x0000000000419d35 in fftw_mkplan_d (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8df930) at planner.c:970
#14 0x00000000004157b1 in mkplan (ego_=0x8df4a0, p_=0x8df650, plnr=0x8d6110)
at rdft2-rank-geq2.c:179
#15 0x0000000000418a07 in invoke_solver (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8df650, s=0x8df4a0,
nflags=0x7fffffff5550) at planner.c:486
#16 0x0000000000418b9c in search0 (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8df650, slvndx=0x7fffffff555c,
flagsp=0x7fffffff5550) at planner.c:529
#17 0x0000000000418db8 in search (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8df650, slvndx=0x7fffffff555c,
flagsp=0x7fffffff5550) at planner.c:600
#18 0x00000000004191d8 in mkplan (ego=0x8d6110, p=0x8df650) at placner.c:711
#19 0x000000000041d1e2 in mkplan0 (plnr=0x8d6110, flags=64, prb=0x8df650, hash_info=0,
wisdom_state=WISDOM_NORMAL) at apiplan.c:34
#20 0x000000000041d229 in mkplan (plnr=0x8d6110, flags=64, prb=0x8df650, hash_info=0)
at apiplan.c:48
#21 0x000000000041d438 in fftw_mkapiplan (sign=0, flags=0, prb=0x8df650)
at apiplan.c:111
#22 0x000000000040a385 in plan_guru_rdft2 (rnk=3, dims0=0x8df540, howmany=1,
r=0x2aab74c21010, c=0x2aab73000010, comm=1140850688, kind=HC2R00, flags=64)
at api.c:784
#23 0x000000000040a542 in fftw_mpi_plan_many_dft_c2r (rnk=3, n=0x7fffffff5830,
howmany=1, iblock=0, oblock=0, in=0x2aab73000010, out=0x2aab74c21010,
comm=1140850688, flags=64) at api.c:831
```